# In source insight, how to directly jump to project window text box?

Tags: shortcut, source-insight

In source insight, to access source file, I use project window very often.
I type few letters or word contained in the name of the file I look for in project window text box to find the target file quickly. 
However, to do that, I need to click the project window text box using mouse and it's a little bit annoying.

The question is "is there any keyboard shortcut to directly get to project window text box?"

Answer (score 0):

I got how to do it.
In [Option] - [Key Assignments], assign your customized key to "Navigation: Activate Project Window". That's it!